# PHP - Performance when executing tasks in exe with php vs same task in php

Tags: php, performance, exe

Is this performance effective (on a Windows Server) to execute tasks in .exe lauched by a php script?

I'm a C# .Net coder and find it way more faster/easier to code directly in C# my backend SQL and 3rd party API functions that requires security, and I would like to know if, on long term, it is good or bad for my website performance to do so.

Will launching executables create a delay in the script, or does the performance (php vs exe) depend on the length of the task to accomplish?

[Edit]

Sorry for the worthless question. I'll search for similar threads on SO and paste some links.

Comment: Why do you need PHP in the first place?

Comment: What do you mean by 'Why do you need PHP in the first place". Because the website is in php.

Comment: If you are going to use c# anyway I don't see the need for any php. I'm not a c# guy, but doesn't it support webservices?

Comment: Launching an .exe with PHP means you will be using something like `exec()` which could potentially be a security risk. Instead, for SQL stuff look into writing User Defined Functions (UDF), and possibly even a module for your web server that contains all the functionality you need to call from PHP.

Comment: So let's say you have a very solid, big website. A guy programmed a complete solution in .exe to update sql, make some payment, etc. You -just -don't want- to translate it in php. Launching the .exe is in itself a stupid idea?

Comment: It might be worth nothing that in your question. Always try to be as complete as possible in your question.

Comment: Anyway. I'm not a web programmer, so I'm maybe better to start reading some documentations right now about why 'executing' something on a website is dangerous.

Comment: Imho the only risk one can potentially have using this method is if the processes somehow hang and accumulate exponentially, which could happen if there is some random unspotted bug in the executables. But other than that, a compiled C# program is always gonna be faster than PHP, so, why not?

Comment: IF you can develop the entire web using C#, then of course that would be even better.

Comment: @Mahn - I guess you mean 'Programming most of the backend parts in C#', and not programming it in ASP.NET C#? Since the question is about launching .exe via php to same on development time, then see if it has a cost on performance.

Comment: I'm not a C# coder, but I suppose developing everything with the same language, including frontend (ASP.NET), is more convenient and easier to maintain in the long run.

Comment: But there's nothing stopping you from using one language for the frontend and another for the backend if it makes sense to you, in itself it's not a bad practice whatsoever.

Comment: And launching an exe via php should not have any penalty in performance at all, the issue would just be what the exectuables do and how you handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is "performance effective" to code the frontend in PHP, and to code the business logic in a more efficient language (which could be C# in your case). This is done often in an SOA (service oriented architecture), which is much more scalable than your idea of doing an `exec` on the same machine, because it allows physical distribution of the workload, but this is not viable for you, apparently.

Your question is not very clear about what you want to `exec`, and especially whether you need the result in a synchronous way, but on a Unix-like machine you could launch the execution in background by terminating the command with a `&`, and anyhow you will also need to redirect `stdin` and `stderr` (see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) for more information).

There is no security risk I know of, as long as you completely sanitize your input, and propery escape your exec parameters.

The timeout mechanism of the web server and the mechanisms which kill a child when a parent is killed will prevent damage by hanging processes, unless they are sent to background. You will probably need a limiting mechanism for the number of concurrent `exec`ed processes, if they are sent to background.

Comment: When a thread began with some comments containing the word 'stupid', I guess there will also be strange 'stupid' downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously there's an overhead from the function call to `exec` (or similar) but the actual execution will be at the same speed, naturally (provided you're not doing anything fancy with the output like line-by-line array storage as one of the execution functions does). I can't imagine the call delay is significant compared to running the program from the shell so I don't think there's much to discuss in the way of efficiency.

As for whether it's a good idea, no, it's probably not.

Comment: Why do you think it's probably a bad idea? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I'm curious too, about why it's probably a bad idea

Comment: I think I worded that too strongly. It's not necessarily a *bad* idea but when I find myself doing it, I usually feel like I've produced an inelegant solution. On the matter of security, it can be made watertight with the right amount of care. However, there's always that room for error waiting dormant until, for example, some later maintenance work -- a risk that probably needn't have been created, especially on Windows where the rules aren't always so strict and the potential damage caused by messing up is higher.